# Azure Mobile App Offline SQLite Sync hanging on Initialize

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a Universal Windows App that uses an offline copy of data that it gets from an Azure Mobile App.

I've created a Portable project referencing the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore and SQLite.Net.Async-PCL NuGet packages.

I have a DataService class that tries to initialize the offline database with following code:

```
if (!_dataSyncClient.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
            {
                _store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(AppConstants.SqliteDatabaseFile);
                _store.DefineTable<Language>();

                var syncCtx = _dataSyncClient.SyncContext;

                await syncCtx.InitializeAsync(_store);
            }
```

But when I try to call this code from a UWA it hangs on the InitializeAsync method, no exceptions, nothing. One thing I noticed that the offline SQLite is being created with an empty Language table and some empty system tables (__config, __erros, __operations).

The UWA has a reference to the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore NuGet package and a reference to the SQLite for Universal App Platform dll version 3.10.2.0.

Comment: I was wondering if it has something to do with the difference between Mobile Services and Mobile Apps, most of the examples I found are for Mobile Services.

Comment: Looks like good code - make sure you are using the latest NuGet packages (v2.0.x) for Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client and Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mobile Apps SQLite store class is **not** compatible with SQLite.NET, as it uses SQLitePCL. It's possible that you trying to access the same SQLite database from the two libraries and that is causing the problem.

If SQLite.NET support is important, you can write your local store implementation, using ours as a starting point: [Mobile Apps SQLiteStore on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/tree/master/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore). The design is flexible enough to let you substitute any local store implementation.

For a working sample based on the built-in `MobileServiceSQLiteStore`, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/windows-uwp-cs. The project has instructions for how to add offline sync support. You need to add the [UWP SQLite VSIX package](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4913e7d5-96c9-4dde-a1a1-69820d615936) and add a reference to [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/).

Comment: Thanks, if it's not possible to combine the SQLite.NET and Mobile Apps SQLite store, how can I use things like DropTable or some sort of transactional actions?

Comment: Updating the answer.

Comment: Hi I am trying to install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore nuget 3.0.3 to UWP app within Xamarin solution, but apparently version 3+ is not compatible as I am able to install it to portable project, to iOS, to Droid but not to UWP.

Comment: @lindydonna all the sources you have mentioned are broken. Can you please point out the latest document or sample? I am trying to encrypt the azure offline DB file.